# SDL - how to use single button as a switch between "on" and "off"?

Tags: c++, events, keyboard, sdl

Can this be done with SDL ? 
What I mean is when you press F1 - "turn on the lights". When you press F1 for a second time - "turn off the lights", and so on. 
A solution to this can be to keep a counter for the button and if it is pressed odd number of times - "turn on lights", if it is pressed even number of times - "turn off lights". 
But if I have 12 buttons for different functions I don't think that's the optimal way to do it, because I will have to keep different counters for each of these 12 buttons.

Comment: You'd want to independently control 12 lights with less than 12 switches? No can do :)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? why counting if there are 2 states **on** and **off**, it's like **1** and **0**.

Comment: @itwasntpete , I need to turn on and off anti-aliasing, lights, previews, etc. It's not bad idea to use bools, but again I need different variable for each button :)

Comment: and what exactly is the problem with 12 variables? you could use vector<bool> and use an index...

Comment: @getoff You want to do it in C++ way or C ? Because creating a class to handle the button is C++ way, else you can use a int and do some bit shift and a binary AND to know if your switch is at on or off, you will be able to handle 31 switches with an int, but this way is more C style.

Comment: @jordsti 1) it's tagged c++. 2) [vector of bools](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/) or [bitfields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) will do that for you. 3) int is not always 32 bit, example 64 bit machine. 4) with 32 bit you are able to handle **32** switches.

Comment: You could even include a simple array like `SwitchState button[12]` in your class, where `SwitchState` is an enum class describing the two states of your buttons (on and off). Or if you don't want to bother with an enum class you could use a bool where `true` has been chosen arbtirarily to correspond to one of the states (either on or off). Then the opposite (`false`) would correspond to the other state.

Comment: Thank you guys, you gave me some nice ideas. I like the bit shift way but I might go with vector<bool>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counter are not a bad idea, and I don't think that the optimal way too. If you use an int to do this, it only 4 byte per counter, so it's not that much.

But in my opinion, you can do this with a bool value, when the value is true, the button is active else, it's not. If will simplify your code too, because you will just need to implement a getter for your bool value, and you will be able to use it in your condition. On and off are binary option, because it's 0 or 1, so the bool represent that exactly.

And just for the conception of your software, you can make a class Button that contains that information and you just create an instance for each of your switches.